# MSSQL2000 How do i bind to localhost only?

Tags: sql-server

How do i make MSSQL2000 listen to 1433/TCP only on 127.0.0.1?

Server Network Utility only gives me the option to change listening port, nothing about address binding.

Comment: No such thing in MSSQL2k i'm afraid. Http://imgur.com/yTDzLzi

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use sql server 2000 for 10 years now, but seems it, by default, binds to all the IP's and that there isn't a way to natively restrict 
this.

What Microsoft seems to suggest in this case is to close sql server port via IPSec using Local Security Policy Editor for all ip address.
And add a rule to allow only 127.0.0.1 on sql server port.
I guess this could be achieved with Windows Firewall also.

Here is my source : http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.sqlserver.security/2004-12/0064.html (follow the thread using "Next in thread" link)

Comment: Nevermind, the 'legacy' application i was trying to secure is doing this (from a client computer):
`TCP    10.xx.xx.57:20922       10.xx.xx.6:1433         TIME_WAIT`
Have to get rid of all this stuff, quick. This spells TROUBLE.